# The Art of Foley library

Tags: foley-editing, sound-libraries

I may be cutting some foley (unfortunately no budget for a walker) for a few low budget horror films, so I'm thinking of purchasing The Art of Foley collection from Sound Ideas. It's on sale for something like half off and it looks like it will have everything I need, but I'm really hesitant to spend any money on 16/44.1 effects, even if it is thousands of them. I'm guessing that for foley applications, it should work fine, but does anyone have any experience working with this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it often. No worry about the 16/44.1

Answer (score 3):

It's an all around good (starter) library - while some stuff is canned since it's been around for so long, it has decent variety and there's a few gems in there.  The content is by [Dan O'Connell](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0640006/), as well-known for his Foley work as [John Roesch](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0736430/).  But like I said, the set's been around for a while so it's slightly dated/canned and doesn't quite have the breadth that many Hard drive/download libraries might offer if there were ones for Foley in the same vain as what the Art of Foley set is all aboout.

44.1/16 should be fine, never been much of an issue for me.  I also don't find myself doing such drastic pitching of Foley stuff anyways, so it's never been a big deal.

I believe you may be taking the "quality" thing too literally on this, sounds audiophile-ish to me (as in, scoffing anything less than 96/24).  44.1/16 WAV is stuff good and usable, it's not like we're talking MP3s here.  Many who have spent decades within this industry have amassed custom libraries of stuff that was often recorded in 44.1/16 or 48/16 (stored in SD2 even!) and they still use those same FX elements today, even though they're not "HD".  They are still sufficient tools to get the job done.  I'm certain they wouldn't NOT use something because it was 44.1 or 48.  Anything below, yes it would be an issue because of the Nyquist limit, but sound elements at 44.1/16 and above is still perfectly applicable to today's technology/standards and in the eyes of any sound professional, fair game to cut with.

Comment: My concern is less about the actual technical quality of 16/44.1 (especially for something like this) and more about the sort of dated sound that you mentioned, which I think a lot of the CD libraries suffer from just based on how long they've been around and how much they've been used. It sounds like that might not be an issue in this case, though, especially since the sounds would be used more subtly than say explosions or gunshots.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [HERE](http://www.signo-sfx-instruments.com/)

cheers